# IPywidgets observe not working when wrapped inside a class

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I have created a small example, which shows the working and not working case.
The working example,

```
import ipywidgets as widgets


selected = {}

a = widgets.Dropdown(description="Apple", options = ["a","k"])
                 
b = widgets.Dropdown(description="Boeing", options = ["a",'b'])
                 
c = widgets.Dropdown(description="Coco Cola", options = ["a",'b','c'])

def getvaluea(change):
    selected["a"] = change.new
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print(selected)

def getvalueb(change):
    selected["b"] = change.new
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print(selected)

def getvaluec(change):
    selected["c"] = change.new
    with out:
        out.clear_output()
        print(selected)

out = widgets.Output()
                     
tab = widgets.Tab()

tab.children = [a,b,c]

tab.titles = ["a",'b','c']

a.observe(getvaluea, 'value')
b.observe(getvalueb, 'value')
c.observe(getvaluec, 'value')

display(tab)

display(out)
```

Using this code example will change add or change items in selected. When I try to wrap this same code sample in a class, I am having a problem getting the result.

```
class UserInterfaceAttempt10:

  def __init__(self):
    
    self.selected = {}
    
    self.a = widgets.Dropdown(description="Apple", options = ["a","k"])
             
    self.b = widgets.Dropdown(description="Boeing", options = ["a",'b'])

    self.c = widgets.Dropdown(description="Coco Cola", options = ["a",'b','c'])
    
    self.out = widgets.Output()
                 
    self.tab = widgets.Tab()

    self.tab.children = [self.a, self.b, self.c]

    self.tab.titles = ["a",'b','c']

    self.a.observe(self.getvaluea)
    self.b.observe(self.getvalueb)
    self.c.observe(self.getvaluec)
    
  def getvaluea(self, change):
    self.selected["a"] = change.new
    with self.out:
        self.out.clear_output()
        print(self.selected)

  def getvalueb(self, change):
    self.selected["b"] = change.new
    with self.out:
        self.out.clear_output()
        print(self.selected)

  def getvaluec(self, change):
    self.selected["c"] = change.new
    with self.out:
        self.out.clear_output()
        print(self.selected)
        
  def display_GUI(self):
    display(self.tab)
    display(self.out)

ob = UserInterfaceAttempt10()
ob.display_GUI()
```

Can someone help me understand the problem? Thank you!

Comment: What errors do you see? What behaviour are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with lots of widgets problems, printing and debugging is your friend.

If you `print(change)` within one of your `getvalue` methods you will see the issue:

[image]

The function is being called many times with just a single widget change. The last change is the one that persists.

If instead your observe call specifies:

`self.a.observe(self.getvaluea, names='value')`

you should see the desired result:

[image]

Comment: This is desired result that I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know why if I try to select the first option it doesn't show up in the dictionary? The work around is to select the second option, and then to select the first option again.

Comment: The widget choice doesn't change, therefore the `observe` function does not fire. You can set `value=None` when creating the widgets to have a null choice to start with.